# In Dagger 2, is it possible to have a component to have multiple parent components

Tags: android, dagger-2

Not sure if this is the right question to ask, but here is the scenario I have with an Android app I am making:

- `AppComponent`, represents the entire app scope
- `UserComponent`, created after a user has logged in and destroyed if user logged out.
- `FeatureComponent`, is a feature that user can access, it has several activities.

The problem I have is that under normal circumstances, `FeatureComponent` is created from `UserComponent` as it is part of what authenticated users get to access. However, I have a "try feature" option that allows the user to access all of `FeatureComponent` without authenticating.

What would be the proper way to handle creation/releasing of `FeatureComponent`, should I have be creating `AuthenticatedFeatureComponent` and `TryOutFeatureComponent` even though almost everything is exactly the same?

thanks.

Comment: Can you add some more details of your use case? Perhaps a simple code example of the components and what modules they use.

Comment: Subscoping is based on inheritance. Multiple inheritance is... strange. Which is why Java doesn't support it, and therefore neither does Dagger.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just break out the components that are different between each other and then create a separate module for each use case that includes the relevant components for each?

This is a lot like your suggestion which I think should work. Is there a reason you are hesitating about it?